# Create, Search, Update in one HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I learn to program with Oracle form decades ago and now I am doing a small database using mySQL and web form with PHP.

I want to make 1 form to do multiple jobs of insert new record, search the record and update (or delete) the record.  Say the form is like the one below:

[image]

I have the insert new record part working OK.

But I want to be able to use the same form for query (for example I put the ID in the form, push search button, and make the query result fill in that same form (text box) in which I can directly change the data (example: the address) then push the update button to update that record.

Is that possible to make using PHP only (no Jscript) and 1 form?  I can query the database but I have difficulty in making the query result to fill in the text box of the same form.  I am newbie in PHP and mySQL and I have not program in the long time.

Comment: What are you going to do when your database fills so you have 2 "john smith" records.

Comment: I have make the query only return 1 record only, if not then it will ask the the user to be more specific and try again.  I have that covered already.

Off Topic: Well, eventually I want to add previous and next button so that the query may return many records and I can browse all records using the same form if possible.

BTW, I am newbie here how can I link a picture as sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple submit buttons, you have to name them differently, like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert"> 
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
```

Then in PHP you just check which one was pressed:

```
if ($_POST['insert']) {
  //insert query
} else if ($_POST['search']) {
  //search query
} else { //could add if here, if you want more checks/safety
  //update query
}
```

You'll have to put all of that into a block like:

```
if(!isset($_POST['insert']) || !isset($_POST['search']) || !isset($_POST['update'])) {
  // make your form here
} else {
  //queries here
}
```

Now you'll check whether any submit button has been pressed and each one will return a different query.

To limit the query to 1 if you only want to show one record when searching. When updating you can't do that. Just add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query.

I hope this is enough of an answer to help you get along.

Comment: Thanks.  I have difficulty in putting the query result to the text box in the form.  Could you elaborate a bit here.

Comment: How to put the result from: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query), $row[1] to <input type=text name=address...>

Comment: You could use javascript. See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp) for a tutorial.

Comment: so there is no way to use php only for that?

Comment: Not without reloading the page, which can mess with form submissal in browsers (as in asking to resubmit form)

Comment: So after the while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) I use something like document.getElementById("address").value= $row(address); for all/each column in records?

Comment: That's why you want to limit your result by 1. You can only paste the last value in the field that way.
If you want to display all results, try posting a table below the form.
Anyway, I wouldn't advise you to not refresh the page. Best is to go to a landing page, or something that looks like it and make the user go back to the form page by link. This solves any form resubmittal issues.